# Run odoo from pycharm using python in windows 7 return database created with access denied

Tags: python, pycharm, odoo

Run odoo from pycharm using python in windows 7 return database created with access denied

software details:

- Run odoo-13
- pycharm 2020.2.1
- python 3.8 (32 bit)
- windows 7 64 bit

Files:

- [odoo.conf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r7SFRfJ8oGHGajU6lB7DtrATgMvpMLDe/view?usp=sharing)
- [pycharm.conf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IZyaCLhveuS9VKD15uzL2QpCS824gAI8/view?usp=sharing)
- [odoo-bin debug](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qxdAaJK_F7xszPBYanDLDZQFUSNAPWj9/view?usp=sharing)
- [odoo create database page](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y16sRBb6W1zXypWyXwRS7OU_I3UozKoy/view?usp=sharing)
- [odoo create database response page](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S4fExcsv9Ivl6LrYUC4zzzI2lurESnXj/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please add your confs / code etc. as text here, not images and definitely not images stored somewhere else. Same thing with any pictures, include them in your question

Comment: I think you role doesn't have privilege to create or access this database, and why there is a danger icon did you create the database using odoo?

Answer (score 0):

please try these commands:

```
sudo su postgres
psql
```

After psql terminal opens then type this:

```
alter role your_role_name with createdb;
```

Answer (score 0):

Odoo 13.0 is not compatible with Python 3.8!